# how can i get firestore collection and subcollection in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Thank you for reading my question.
My English may not be good enough before I ask you a question.

this my firestore structure
[image: this my firestore structure]
[image: this my firestore structure]

I'm using a flutter and I have to bring the product collection and subcollection image together from the FireStore.

I succeeded get data, but I don't know how to use it as a streambuilder.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("products")
                  .get()
                  .then((value) async => {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document in value.docs)
                          {
                            log(document.data().toString()),
                            await document.reference
                                .collection("images")
                                .get()
                                .then((value) => {
                                      for (DocumentSnapshot document
                                          in value.docs)
                                        {
                                          log(document.data().toString()),
                                        }
                                    }),
                          }
                      });
```

code run log result
[image]

I looked for it for three days, but I couldn't find the answer.
Please reply.

Have a nice day. Thank you.

Comment: You could use an array of images in the same collection rather than using a sub-collection. It will reduce costs when the app scales.

Comment: The only way I have found to do this is to use 2 different streambuilders, naming each snapshot differently.  Use one for the products collection, then images for the other.  What I would recommend is to add a field of 'images' in your product document and make it an array of string types.  This will allow you to reference the images straight from each product document.  Amon, you beat me by 2 mins.

Comment: Wow, Thank you, Amon and Scott, for your good answers.

Comment: @ScottGodfrey Consider writing an answer with the information of your comment as others can benefit of that information.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found to do this is to use 2 different streambuilders, naming each snapshot differently. Use one for the products collection, then images for the other. What I would recommend is to add a field of 'images' in your product document and make it an array of string types. This will allow you to reference the images straight from each product document